# Shared group calendar for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Can anyone point me towards a free group calendar solution in ASP.NET VB?

Basically anyone in the company should be able to access it from their computer and make changes to it. I would assume its MSSQL sever based.

ETA: It doesn't HAVE to be VB, C# or Silverlight would be OK, however I'm not too hot on either of those languages myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, does this have to be via ASP? Google calenders works fine. Or, do you have exchange?

Comment: Not necessarily - although building it into the intranet (which I'm currently building) would allow a greater deal of possible integration. 

I had not considered a hosted service like google calendars - however thanks for the suggestion - i'll have a look over it.

No, the company's IT systems are a bit of a mish-mash from previous take-overs, however Exchange is on the to-do list, so would be the best option, once in place.

Comment: From what it sounds like, (and I know the feelings :) ), I would use Google Calender as an interim solution and then move to Exchange - the fact you don't have Exchange today suggests it's a small company (?) and therefore this would be managable. Hope this helped.

Comment: sadly its not "small", not huge but not small (11 sites, 1400 employees) - to make life harder for me they are using Active directory for logins etc, but do not keep user data in AD (phone numbers etc)

Comment: From the sounds of it, getting Exchange would be quicker than building the calender from scratch.

Comment: yes... the calendar isn't something they have specifically said they need, so I'm just scoping out the possibilities right now.

Comment: You could try something from codeplex such as http://codeplex.codeplex.com/site/search?query=calendar&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=| (and you can filter from right side menu)